# efficicent way to write multiple jquery functions

Tags: jquery, simplify

I have multiple divs, and I have to write a code like this out for each div, and have php change the id by cycling through $NBR++; at the end. Is there a quicker way to write this once rather than to have this unique for each div?

```
   // when $NBR = 1
   <div class="playbutton<?php echo $NBR?>">
       <script>
           $(".playbutton<?php echo $NBR?>").click(function()
              {  $(".playbutton<?php echo $NBR?>").hide();
                 $('#songpicture').attr("src", "<?php echo $thumb[$NBR]?>");
              });
       </script>
   </div>


   // when $NBR = 2
   <div class="playbutton<?php echo $NBR?>">
       <script>
           $(".playbutton<?php echo $NBR?>").click(function()
              {  $(".playbutton<?php echo $NBR?>").hide();
                 $('#songpicture').attr("src", "<?php echo $thumb[$NBR]?>");
              });
       </script>
   </div>
```

This goes on 15 times ...etc.....All php variable are set at the beginning of each div with PHP.

So is there a way that I can 'compress' this into one code that could be written once? Or must it be written after each div?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you need to explain / clarify please let me know....
These jquery codes are taking up too much space :/

Comment: Why can't you use a simple `for` loop?

Comment: I'll have to learn about the .each() loop for jquery, I never used it.
Thanks I'll give this a try!

Comment: @DankPiff I think he is talking about php iterate to generate those div's.

Comment: Oh, thats what I'm using now, But I wanted to consolidate all the code to one script rather than have PHP write it out individually for each div. The whole site is dynamic

Comment: Either case... I don't follow what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this in the top and remove all other script,

```
 <script>
  $(function () {
     $(".playback_divs").click(function() {  
       $(this).hide();
       $('#songpicture').attr("src", $(this).data('thumb-nbr'));
     });
  }
 </script>
```

And change your html as,

```
<div class="playback_divs playbutton<?php echo $NBR?>" data-thumb-nbr="<?php echo $thumb[$NBR]?>">
```

Note the html changes

1) new class `playback_divs` added to the div.

2) the data attr `data-thumb-nbr`.

Comment: Thanks for your help...
In my code there are many more things jquery does once the div is clicked, I just put two for example.

I'll give this a try thanks!

Comment: So can I just add new 'attributes' ( I don't know what to call them) like data-thumb-nbr to divs, and then have jquery reference them?